# Doctrine: change format before populating field?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

In my table all prices are stored as strings in `245,95` format (european format). I can't change this.
Internally in my app I would like all prices as floats.

Can I have doctrine to change the format before populating the entity field? In plain sql I can use a `REPLACE` and accomplish what I want.

I have been looking at Symfony data transfomers but it looks like it is only for forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the conversion logic in the getter method .

```
.
.
.
function getPrice(){
      $price = conversionLogic($this->price);
      return $price;
}
.
.
.
```